# Integrate using $t$ substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

integrate this $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$

I took $\sqrt{x} = t$

Differentiated it

So $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{dt}{dx}$

Then I don't know how to proceed

I did some steps and it got too complicated

I also took  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}} = t$

But that also got complicated

A hint would be perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: A substitution like $t = \sqrt{x}$ is tricky to make work, since then $\sqrt{x+1}$ is not easily expressible in terms of either $t$ or $dt.$ Instead, try rationalizing the detnominator, using the identity

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}}{a - b}.$$

Comment: Ya I also tried this step
But couldn't proceed after this
After rationalising it u get $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$.then what should I take as t?

Comment: You don't take anything as $\ t.\ $ You can integrate both $\ \sqrt{x}\ $ and $\ \sqrt{x+1}\ $ directly. $\ \sqrt{x+1}\ = (x+1)^{\frac12}...$

Comment: Oh yes!! Totally forgot about this.Anyways thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0):

**A COMPLICATED SOLUTION:**

Let $$\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{x}=u, \quad \sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{x}=1/u \implies 2\sqrt{x}=u-1/u~~~~(*)$$
So we get $dx=\frac{(u^4-1)}{4u^2} du$
So $$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\int (1-\frac{1}{u^4}) dx$$
$$\implies I= \frac{1}{2} \left(u+\frac{1}{3u^3}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{x})^3\right)$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2}{3}[(1+x)^{3/2}-x^{3/2}].$$
Such tranformation as (*) solve more interesting problems.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!